# Mapping array to an existing Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to deep copy data from a C++ array to an Eigen matrix. So I did this:

```cpp
foo(const Input &input){
   Eigen::MatrixXf data = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf>(input.data, input.rows, input.cols);
}
```

The`Input`struct is like this:

```
Struct Input{
  float data[600 * 600];
  int cols;
  int rows;
}
```

You may already see that there is **non-const** conversion problem, as the compiler complains that "invalid conversion from `const float*` to `float*`".

For some reason, I have to keep the input to be `const` reference. So I changed my code to this:

```cpp
foo(const Input &input){
   Eigen::MatrixXf data = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXf>(input.data, input.rows, input.cols);
}
```

If I do like that, is my deep copy still effective？

Comment: Yes, it is still a copy. Why wouldn't it be? While we are at it, you can simplify the right side into ```Eigen::MatrixXf::Map(input.data, input.rows, input.cols)```. It will automatically change between const and non-const depending on the pointer

Comment: Thank you Homer. Can you explain more about why adding `const` on the right side fix the non-const conversion problem? I think the left side is still a non-const type, and the right side is still a const type, no matter adding the `const` or not.

Comment: ```Map``` is a distinct type from ```Matrix```. ```Map``` *borrows* memory that was allocated somewhere else. ```Matrix``` *owns* its memory. ```Map<const …>``` is a template specialization for const pointers that does not allow changing the memory. On the right hand side you create a ```Map<const …>```, then on the left side assign it to a ```Matrix```. This invokes the conversion constructor of ```Matrix``` that copies the elements from the ```Map``` into newly allocated memory owned by the ```Matrix```